# Pausar um gif em um determinado frame, parecido com o facebook

Tags: javascript

Olá,

Tenho uma duvida, preciso pausar um gif exatamente no frame que aparece na tela, similar ao que vemos no facebook. [Esse link de exemplo](https://www.facebook.com/playthegif/posts/1850336515194730)

Até o momento, a unica coisa que eu consegui fazer, foi dar play e pause em um gif, mas alternando entre o gif animado por uma imagem estática (Usando o GIF Player).

[Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/k9s3fk8u/) tem um pouco do que eu fiz até o momento usando o GIF Player

Talvez o que eu fiz até o momento não tenha nada a ver com o que preciso, alguém pode me dar uma luz, por gentileza?

Obrigado!

Comment: Esse link seu do facebook mostra um .mp4 e não um Gif. Se quer ter esse controle todo, provavelmente vai ter que fazer o mesmo que eles: converter pra outro formato. Alternativamente existem soluções como o http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/ que pegam um GIF, fazem o _parse_ e redesenham em um canvas, mas talvez a conversão em vídeo ainda seja melhor para arquivos grandes.